# How is this version of Chernoff bound derived?

Tags: probability

Theorem for additive form (absolute error) of Chernoff bound from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_additive_form_.28absolute_error.29), which I take for granted:

> Assume random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m$ are i.i.d. Let $p = E
>  \left [X_i \right ], X_i \in \{0,1\}$, and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $$
>          \begin{align} &\Pr\left[ \frac 1 m \sum X_i \geq p + \varepsilon \right] \\ &\qquad\leq \left ( {\left (\frac{p}{p +
>  \varepsilon}\right )}^{p+\varepsilon} {\left (\frac{1 - p}{1 -p -
>  \varepsilon}\right )}^{1 - p- \varepsilon}\right ) ^m = e^{ -
>  D(p+\varepsilon\|p) m} \end{align}  $$ and $$
>          \begin{align} &\Pr\left[ \frac 1 m \sum X_i \leq p - \varepsilon \right] \\ &\qquad\leq \left ( {\left (\frac{p}{p -
>  \varepsilon}\right )}^{p-\varepsilon} {\left (\frac{1 - p}{1 -p +
>  \varepsilon}\right )}^{1 - p+ \varepsilon}\right ) ^m = e^{ -
>  D(p-\varepsilon\|p) m}, \end{align}  $$ where $$
>          D(x||y) = x \log \frac{x}{y} + (1-x) \log \frac{1-x}{1-y}  $$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between Bernoulli distributed
>   random variables with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I was wondering how the next statement is derived:

> If $p\geq 1/2 $, then $\Pr\left[ X>mp+x \right] \leq
>  \exp(-x^2/2mp(1-p)) $.

I thought it might be derived from the first formula, 
$$\Pr\left[ X>mp+x \right] 
= \Pr\left[ X/m >p+x/m \right] 
\leq e^{ - D(p+x/m\|p) m}
 $$
where
$$
D(p+x/m\|p)
= (p+x) \ln \frac{p+x}{p} + (1-p-x) \ln \frac{1-p-x}{1-p}
$$
but I couldn't reach $\exp(-x^2/2mp(1-p))$ from here.

Thanks!